# how can I get the data pointer of a string variable in go?

Tags: pointers, go, cgo

I want to get the data pointer of a string variable(like string::c_str() in c++) to pass to a c function and I found this doesn't work:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
void Println(const char* str) {printf("%s\n", str);}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    s := "hello"
    C.Println((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&(s[0]))))
}
```

Compile error info is: 'cannot take the address of s[0]'. 
This will be OK I but I doubt it will cause unneccesary memory apllying. Is there a better way to get the data pointer?

```
C.Println((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&([]byte(s)[0]))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to get the underlying data from a Go string to C without copying it. It will not work as a C string because it is not a C string. Your printf will not work even if you manage to extract the pointer even if it happens to work sometimes. Go strings are not C strings. They used to be for compatibility when Go used more libc, they aren't anymore.

Just follow the cgo manual and use `C.CString`. If you're fighting for efficiency you'll win much more by just not using cgo because the overhead of calling into C is much bigger than allocating some memory and copying a string.

Comment: Re your last statement - "the overhead of calling into C is much bigger than allocating some memory and copying a string" - do you have any benchmarks to back that up?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer In fact, I do. From a year ago: https://github.com/art4711/cgo_overhead  If I get time I'll update it to 1.8.

Comment: Updated for 1.8. In 1.8 it's just 36 times slower instead of 92 times slower to make a cgo function call compared to a Go function call.

Comment: jesus! I wasn't aware it was so expensive. what causes this?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Many things. It needs to change the stack, many of the normal "this function doesn't use stack" optimizations are disabled, a bunch of stuff is run to make sure that we're not violating garbage collector rules (even when the C function takes no arguments), etc.

Comment: C can work with Go strings just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`(*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&sourceTail)).Data`

Strings in go are not null terminated, therefore you should always pass the `Data` and the `Len` parameter to the corresponding C functions. There is a family of functions in the C standard library to deal with this type of strings, for example if you want to format them with printf, the format specifier is `%.*s` instead of `%s` and you have to pass both, the length and the pointer in the arguments list.